# Grails : getting assets local storage path inside the controller

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I need to extract the assets folder physical path in order to write a file from my controller.

Any short way of achieving the file persistency from the controller?

Answer (score 2):

Complete example:

```
class ExampleService {
  def assetResourceLocator

  def someMethod() {
    Resource res = assetResourceLocator.findAssetForURI('test.css')
    String url = res.getURL()
    String uri = res.getURI()
  }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39642278/717267

Answer (score 0):

Look at the AssetProcessorService inside the plugin. There are different function to get the path like **getAssetPath** or **getResolvedAssetPath**. This might help you.