# Grails 3 - get asset path in service

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-3.0, grails-services

I need to get the path of a static resource located in `assets/schemas/resource.json` in a Grails 3 service.

At the moment it is defined as

```
private final String SCHEMA = 'grails-app/assets/schemas/resource.json',
```

which is fine for `development` environment, but of course not for production (as it would be located in `<app_root>/assets/resource.json`.

I tried to search how to exploit the Asset Pipeline in my case, but up to now I really have no idea :P

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is covered in the docs.
http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html

In a controller or service, inject the `assetResourceLocator` and use `assetResourceLocator.findAssetForURI()`

Comment: You're right :)
The solution for my problem would have been `assetResourceLocator.findAssetForURI('schemas/resource.json').getURI()` (or alternatively `.getURL()`), but I later decided to put my json file in `src/main/resources` as I really didn't need it to be managed as an asset but as a simple resource.

Answer (score 7):

It works locally but not when deployed to a server. Using Grails 3.1.0, Java 1.8.0_91 and Tomcat 8.0.33.

```
assetResourceLocator?.findAssetForURI('myFolder/placeholder.jpg')?.byteArray
```

returns

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: byteArray for class: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource

**EDIT: Solved it:**

```
assetResourceLocator?.findAssetForURI('myFolder/placeholder.jpg')?.getInputStream()?.bytes
```

Comment: thanks, I had the same problem (working in development, but not in production). This solution worked for me too in grails 2.4.5!

Comment: Does the inputstream here need to be closed?

Answer (score 1):

Complete example:

```
class ExampleService {
  def assetResourceLocator

  def someMethod() {
    Resource res = assetResourceLocator.findAssetForURI('test.css')
    String url = res.getURL()
    String uri = res.getURI()
  }
}
```

Source: http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html